# Absolute convergence, reordering and logical reasoning.

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have to prove the following theorem.

> Let $\sum a_n$ be a complex or real series absolutely convergent. Then each of its rearrangements is absolutely convergent. Furthermore, if the series $\sum a_n$ it is not absolutely convergent, then none of its rearrangements are.

Now, if I have a series that converges for every rearrangement, can I conclude that the series converges absolutely? My answer is yes, otherwise if the series were not absolutely convergent for the previous result none of its rearrangements should be absolutely convergent.

Is this logical reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. If the series was not absolutely convergent then all that you could deduce from the previous theorem would be that *some* of its rearrangements would not be absolutely convergent (which is trivial; just take the original series).

But it is true that if a series converges for every rearrangement, then that series converges absolutely. This follows from Riemann's rearrangement theorem.